# Use KeyEvent in Button onClick

Tags: android, onclick, keyevent

I want to use KeyEvent example KEYCODE_0 [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_0)
 in button onClick

```
<Button
              android:id="@+id/Btnequal_id"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="60dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:onClick="0x00000007"
              android:text="=" />
```

Comment: The onClick() method has no argument for a KeyEvent. Also, you must specify a method name for the value in the android:onClick field.

Comment: thanks and if i declared the keyEvent in the method how i will do that

Comment: You cannot get the KeyEvent in the onClick method. `onKeyDown()` is a method that you can override in an Activity or View that passes in a KeyEvent as a parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry but i do not understand fully how i can use the KeyEvents

Comment: To get any key event you have to override certain methods in you activity e.g. onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event), onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) depending upon your requirement. In these methods you can check the key code for what you are looking for and perform the desired task.

Comment: appreciate your help thanks to you but I think i have to sleep i understand nothing I will reread your answer tomorrow and thanks for your help again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get instance of your EditText on which you wanna apply keyEvent listener,then setOnKeyListner on your edittext like below.

```
mPinBox4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinVerifyBox4);

    mPinBox4.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0){
                //excute what ever you want when KEYCODE_0 is pressed
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You can up vote my answer if it works for you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

onKeyEvent can be applied on EditText.I think you are asking wrong question.
Please clear me if ,Iam wrong.

Comment: yes i mean apply KeyEvents effects on an EditText like and internal keyboard for the app also I am disabling user keyboard inputing in calculator app